# How to get values from stores and insert into products table?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to statements, so please come slowly on me. I have checked questions asked by others but didnt see a solution to solve my issue.

I am trying to create a userpage with prepared statements so they can add products to their stores.
I would like to get store_id from stores and insert into produtcs on an insert product form.

I have tried several methods but they didnt work.
Here are my attempts:

Connection

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(host, dbase, username, password);
```

**First method prepare statements:** I have tried this method without bind_result too.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO products (user_id, cat_id, store_id, item_name, item_code, item_description, item_qtty, item_price, item_seo_url, item_image, item_date) SELECT store_id FROM stores WHERE user_id = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $user_id = filterString($_SESSION['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($store_id);
        if($stmt->fetch()){
        echo " Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page";
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    } else{
        echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
       }
}
$stmt->close();
```

**Second method sql prepare statements:** I have tried this too but didnt work:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO products (user_id, cat_id, store_id, item_name, item_code, item_description, item_qtty, item_price, item_seo_url, item_image, item_date) SELECT ?, store_id FROM stores WHERE user_id = ?";
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param("iiisiisiisss", $user_id, $cat_id, $store_id, $item_name, $item_code, $item_description, $item_qtty, $item_price, $item_seo_url, $item_image, $item_date);
    $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $cat_id = $cat_id;
    $store_id = $store_id;
    $item_name = $item_name;
    $item_code = $item_code;
    $item_description = $item_description;
    $item_qtty = $item_qtty;
    $item_price = $item_price;
    $store_seo_url = seo_url($item_name);
    $item_image = $vtyol;
    $item_date = $date;
    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo " Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page";
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    } else{
        echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
    }
}
$stmt->close();
```

Didnt have a chance to get store_id from stores, I echo store ID in page to see if I get it, its empty.
how can I make it work ?
Do I need to declare all values in bind_param in first method ? (I tried and didnt work).
if so, how to add clause `$stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);`.

I really dont know what else to try, need your advice and helps.
Gtg to hospital now be back in 1 hour, will answer your questions and answers.

Thank you all

Last example I tried with the code from @Michael Eugene Yuen it keep saying something went wrong, because of cant get $store_id from stores table.
My codes were to long so I shortened them and tried getting same result.

Here is last example not wroking:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (
user_id, store_id, name, salary
)  
 SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?,
`store_id` FROM stores WHERE user_id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("iisii", $user_id, $store_id, $name, $salary, $user_id);
    $user_id = $user_id;
    $store_id = $store_id;
    $name = $name;
    $salary = $salary;
    if($stmt->execute()){
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    } else{
        echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
    }
$stmt->close();
```

Database struckter for both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `salary` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stores` (
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `salary` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`store_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `stores` (`store_id`, `user_id`, `name`, `salary`) VALUES
(1, '12', 'aaaaaaaaaaad', 12),
(2, '12', 'sada', 1234656);
```

Comment: maybe do you have an error?

Comment: All error types are on in my php.ini file, Don’t get error in form, first method giving Boolen error, value is emtpy second method no errors but store id returns empty.

Comment: how do you get this: $user_id on the first and second method please

Comment: user_id  column name is ($user_id) in both table for info. That is the problem, I don’t get $user_id. it’s empty when I echo it or try to insert in database. @Tegito123

Comment: please put your code how get $user_id

Comment: oops tought you asking Store_id, no need to get user_id, I use $_SESSION[id]; to insert. I am at hospital right now will be at home in 30 minutes. Codes are in question, all I have.   @Tegito123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your were trying to insert data into 11 columns but only 1 value was passed into your statements

Your statement should look like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (
            user_id, cat_id, item_name, item_code, item_description,
            item_qtty, item_price, item_seo_url, item_image, item_date,
            store_id
                )
        SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
               ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
               `store_id` FROM stores WHERE user_id = ?";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
```

Bind your $user_id twice. The first one is for your first placeholder and the last one is for your sub-select statement ([bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php))

```
$stmt->bind_param("iisisiisssi", $user_id, $cat_id, $item_name, $item_code, $item_description, $item_qtty, $item_price, $item_seo_url, $item_image, $item_date, $user_id);

$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
$cat_id = $cat_id;
$item_name = $item_name;
$item_code = $item_code;
$item_description = $item_description;
$item_qtty = $item_qtty;
$item_price = $item_price;
$store_seo_url = seo_url($item_name);
$item_image = $vtyol;
$item_date = $date;

if($stmt->execute()){
        echo " Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page";
        $stmt->close();         
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
} else{
        echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
}
```

**And based on your newly added Example 2**, the number of columns, placeholders mismatch the number of bind_param again. Also, when you look at your stores table, you have two records under the same user_id. So which store_id you expect to insert to your store table?

I have used `LIMIT 1` for now but certainly this is not the correct approach.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (
            user_id, name, salary, store_id
        )  
        SELECT ?, ?, ?, `store_id` FROM stores WHERE user_id = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("isii", $user_id, $name, $salary, $user_id);
$user_id = 12;
$name = 'john';
$salary = 1200;
if($stmt->execute()){
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
}
$stmt->close();
```

This is an sql statement with hardcoded values:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (
            user_id, name, salary, store_id
        )
        SELECT 12, 'john', 1200,
        `store_id` FROM stores WHERE user_id = 12 LIMIT 1";
```

This is same statement with variables:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (
           user_id, name, salary, store_id
        )
        SELECT $user_id, $name, $salary,
        `store_id` FROM stores WHERE user_id = $user_id LIMIT 1";
```

This is same statement with placeholders:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (
        user_id, name, salary, store_id
        )  
        SELECT ?, ?, ?,
        `store_id` FROM stores WHERE user_id = ? LIMIT 1";

$stmt->bind_param("isii", $user_id, $name, $salary, $user_id);
$user_id = 12;
$name = 'john';
$salary = 1200;
```

Comment: I didnt think I will need to add values, I watch some similer examples on youtube they were not using `values(?,?)`, then I removed them, I was using like this ` (values(?,?) SELECT ` wrong way :) I will try your update in a few minutes, Thank you very much. @Michael Eugene Yuen

Comment: keep saying something went wrong, because cant get store_id from stores table, I have shortened code and database tables, adding them to question. @Michael Eugene Yuen

Comment: Thanks for your afford @Michael Eugene Yuen all examples in your updated answer are working like a charm. my bad! I was adding more place holder to bind variable. Cant thank you enough.